# How to make Windows 10 photos program not zoom to fit before viewing at actual size?

Tags: windows-10, images, windows-photo-viewer

When browsing through screenshots of games, that are smaller than the screen size, using the Win 10 photos program, it will show an "always zoom to fit" sized image, briefly, before showing the "always view actual size" image, which is not a pleasant browsing experience.

Is there a way to make it not do that?

I would like to just view the screenshots of a game in order without the constant flashing of a "zoomed to fit" image before the "actual size" image is displayed.

EXTRA INFO:

I should have included some more information but I thought maybe someone had also experienced this and had a quick and easy solution.

My screen resolution is set at 1920 x 1080.

Some of the image sizes are for example: 1536 x 864, 1366 x 768, 1024 x 768, 800 x 600, 640 x 480, etc.

I noticed that when browsing through the first 11 images in a folder, they will be shown at their actual size without the initial full screen flickering, but then from the 12th image onwards they will all flicker from the full-screen zoomed size and then show their actual size.

This happens with folders of images of all the same size, and also folders of images of various sizes.  Even when opening the 11th image in the folder first and then browsing to the next one, the problem happens with the very next one onwards.

When starting with the last image in a folder, then it happens for some and not for others but I'm not sure what the pattern is.  When doing that it starts to seem random.

Also often after viewing a photo that flickered, and the going back to view the same photo, it doesn't flicker again if the program has not been closed.  After closing and re-opening the program then those same images will flicker once again for that session.

For the readers that have tried this and not experienced the same issue, please try to browse through at least 12 of the images consecutively.

I may just start using another program but this seems like something that should or could be fixed.

Comment: It might just be easier to use a free third-party app, such as IrfanView, that allows complete freedom to specify size.

Comment: As above. Also, I don't seem to have that problem on latest WIndows 10 with everthing upgraded in Microsoft Store. Could you provide more details, like consecutive image sizes for which it happens?

Comment: If it happens after 10 images, it looks like obvious software bug that you can't do anything about most likely. Submit a bug report to Microsoft.

Comment: @Destroy666 Did you try browsing through more than 12 images as I described above and not have the same problem?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I didn't try. But I tried now and it happens after 10 I think, so yea, like I said, a bug you should report.